# Card game, combinations and permutations (suits, aces, none, some spades, minimum spades)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, card-games

I do really need help with this question, and it might be a newby question but unfortunately I am unsure of the answer.

In this game each player gets 5 cards from a standard deck of 52 cards. How many sets of 5 cards are there where:

$\textbf{a) All 5 are the same suit?}$

$\textbf{b) 4 aces are part of the 5 cards?}$

$\textbf{c) none of the 5 cards have the same number?}$

$\textbf{d) Exactly 2 of the 5 cards are spades?}$

$\textbf{e) At least two of the 5 cards are spades?}$

I don't know if I am approaching this right although I did this $C(52, 3) \cdot C(52 - 5, 3) \cdot C(47 - 5, 3) \cdot C(42 - 5, 3) \cdot C(37 - 5, 3) \cdot C(32 - 5, 3) \cdot C(27 - 5, 3)*C(22 - 5, 3) \cdot C(17 - 5, 3) \cdot C(12 - 5, 3) \cdot C(7 - 5, 3)$

I did this because they are sets of cards, but I am probably misunderstanding the question?

b) $C(52+5-1,52-1)$

c) $C(52, 5)$

d) $C(5, 2)$

e) $P(5, 2)$

I don't know if the word sets is trowing me off or something, I am really confused and really would like to find the answer because I have an exam in 4 days on this and things were explained in a huge rush.

Comment: You are asking : how many ways are there to pick 5 cards such that $a,b,c,d,e$ happen (answer is separate for each case, that is)? The context of the game confused me,

Comment: Yeah sorry the game is not specified, and this question is kinda of trowing me off to me too, but yeah, I am asking how many ways basically such that $a,b,c,d,e$ happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All are the same suit.

We need $5$ cards of the same the suit. How do we get that? First we choose a suit, there are $4$ to chose from. Then from the $13$ cards in the suit, we choose $5$ cards. So the answer by the multiplication principle is,

$$4 {13 \choose 5}$$

---

> 4 aces are part of the five cards.

We need four aces then any other card. How do we do this. Out of the $4$ aces we choose all $4$. Then we chose any other card, there are $48$ other cards to choose from.

$$48 {4 \choose 4}$$

---

> Exactly two are spades.

We need two spades and three other cards. How do we get this? Choose $2$ spades from the $13$ in the deck. Then choose $3$ non-spades from the $52-13=39$ non-spades in the deck.

$${13 \choose 2} {39 \choose 3}$$

---

> At least two are spades.

We can get: two spades, three non-spades. Three spades, two non-spades. Four spades, one non-spade. Five spades, zero non-spades.

To get $k$ spades. Choose $k$ out of the $13$ in the deck. Then to get $5-k$ non-spades choose $5-k$ from the $39$ non-spades in the deck. We may get $k=2,3,4,5$

$$\sum_{k=2}^{5} {13 \choose k}{39 \choose 5-k}$$

Comment: When you say $\binom{52}{5}$ you always mean combination correct?For permutation you always use $P(52, 5)$ right?

Comment: For b shouldn't it be out of 4 aces we choose for but 1 card can be anything so $47 \cdot \binom{5}{4}$

Comment: Yes I mean combination, we chose $4$ aces out of $4$ aces in the deck. Then we chose whatever card.

Comment: Another question, so if I did said though, you have to have 4 suits in order, then I would have chosen a permutation, not combination correct? Also, if I said instead of $5$ cards $13$ (on a for the 4 aces) then it would have been $4 \cdot \binom{13}{13}$, and that's because I have 4 aces and 13 choose 13 right? Other and last for "at least 2 are spades" why k = 2 in the summation? Shouldn't k = 1 because there is ace of spades?

Comment: What do you man $4$ suits in order? Also I don't quite understand your notification, may you please elaborate?

Comment: like hearts 1 2 3 4?I also edited the question added: "Other and last for "at least 2 are spades" why k = 2 in the summation? Shouldn't k = 1 because there is ace of spades?"

Comment: $k=1$ means your including the possibility that we get exactly $1$ spade and $4$ non-spades. But we want at least $2$ spades. I'm sorry I don't understand what your trying to say, perhaps you may add it as a question and I'll answer you.

Comment: No no problem, yeah I ll probably try to rephrase it, although I pretty much understood, you really gave a great explanation, and I ll give you in the answer point